# macOS notify_keys.h constant in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, system

How do I use the constant of `/usr/include/notify_keys.h` in Swift code? Which documentation should I refer to for the key beside of the actual header file?

I am using [CFNotification​Center​](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corefoundation/cfnotificationcenter-rkv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to add a bridging header file to your project and import the notif_keys.h file in the bridging header file. If you need additional information on how to do this, please ask and I'll expand upon the answer.

Comment: so, there is no "native" way of using it in Swift? I'm using only one key from the file, currently I just "hard code" the constant in my source file.

Comment: That is the native way to do it since that's how you bring in Objective-C classes, constants etc. into Swift :)

Comment: Another question, why I can't find documentation about those keys online beside of just the header file.

Comment: I'm afraid that's a question I can't answer since documentation depends on Apple. They might not have added the documentation for one reason or another and if they did not, there's nothing much we can do except to go through the source to figure out what is going on ...

If the above answer solved your issue, could you please mark it as "correct"?